# If I have a type defined as a string constant, why can't I pass that type to functions as an actual string?

Tags: go

Here's what I mean: [Go playground](http://play.golang.org/p/67U2AOAlsa)

The "StringType" type is a string and nothing more.  The compiler complains about line 21, but for some reason, line 16 works without issue (if you comment 21 and uncomment 22).

What is the difference between those two lines (as both as passing StringType to the same function), and why does one work and the other not?

Here's the code, in-line:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

type StringType string

const (
    FirstString  = "first"
    SecondString = "second"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println(strings.Contains(FirstString, SecondString))    // line 16
}

func myFunc(a StringType, b StringType) bool {

    return strings.Contains(a, b)                               // line 21
    //return false
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go has a strict typing system. `StringType` and `string` is not the same type, and you need to do a type conversion.

The Go specs states that:

> A non-constant value x can be converted to type T in any of these cases:
>
> x is assignable to T.
>   x's type and T have identical underlying types.
>   ...
>   x is an untyped constant representable by a value of type T

Since `StringType` has the underlying type of `string`, this conversion is possible:

```
func myFunc(a StringType, b StringType) bool {

    return strings.Contains(string(a), string(b))
    //return false
}
```

Also, because `FirstString` and `SecondString` are untyped constants representable by StringType, this will allow you to pass it as a `StringType`, as stated by the specs.

Comment: OK, your last sentence is what did it for me.  I always assumed that since I defined the constants immediately below the type definition that the constants were of that type.

Answer (score 0):

In the first case, you're passing strings, no problem.

In the second one, you pass `StringType` values instead of strings. You need to tell the compiler they're strings by converting them :

Replace

```
return strings.Contains(a, b)
```

with

```
return strings.Contains(string(a), string(b))
```

Comment: So in the first case, why is FirstString considered a string and not a StringType?  It is defined as type StringType.

Comment: No, you never define FirstString as StringType. `FirstString  = "first"` makes it of type `string`.

Comment: Then why can I pass FirstString to myFunc as type StringType?  See http://play.golang.org/p/o_HRfUYiuK

Comment: @Darrrrrren: See my answer. It is because untyped constants can be converted to any type representable by the value.

Answer (score 0):

Because `StringType` is *not* of type `string` it cannot be assigned to anything of type `string`. Go is a strongly typed language. But as the underlying types of `StringType` and `string` are the same, you can use a [conversion](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions):

```
return strings.Contains(string(a), string(b))
```